# With a merge conflict at hand, is there an easy way to diff the common ancestor with the version being merged in?

Tags: git

Commands like 'git diff -1 config/routes' always diff against the working copy.  I'm interested in seeing just "their" diffs.

I can dump out the files and diff them manually like this:

```
git show :1:config/routes.rb > common
git show :3:config/routes.rb > theirs
diff common theirs
```

Wondering if there is an easier way.

Thx,
Dan

Answer (score 2):

```
git config merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

Enables you to see the common ancestor (between ||||| and ====) when the merge has been done.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
.. from HEAD
|||||||
.. from common ancestor
=======
.. from master
>>>>>>> master
```

See the following blog for more details:

http://blog.wuwon.id.au/2010/09/painless-merge-conflict-resolution-in.html

Comment: most needed, this should be default

Answer (score 1):

I got some solutions from the IRC channel.  The simplest was:

```
git diff :1:config/routes.rb :3:config/routes.rb
```

Another option was:

```
alias a="git merge-base HEAD MERGE_HEAD"
git diff $(a)..MERGE_HEAD config/routes.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>There is `git diff -c` or `git diff --cc` which you can use.</strike>

Edit:

I think that may not be what you want:

Think `git diff HEAD...MERGE_HEAD` is what you are looking for?